# How to escape quotes immediately following each other?

Tags: php, regex

I want to escape all double quotes which are NOT escaped already.

I am using **real_escape_string()** already, but I wish to understand what is wrong with the follow regular expression/approach:

```
$str = '"Hello "" """ world!\"';
preg_replace('/(^|[^\\\\]{1})\"/', '${1}\"', $str);
```

(PS: I know - **\\"** will NOT be escaped and MIGHT be a problem in some other cases though this doesn't matter to my script.)

The result was:

```
\"Hello \"" \""\" world!\"
```

But I wanted it to be:

```
\"Hello \"\" \"\"\" world!\"
```

Comment: For an SQL insert you should **not, under any circumstances, roll your own escaping**. Use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: This is a bad idea, but a quick way you can do this is: 1) Replace all of the escaped quotes with an un-escaped quote, then 2) replace all of the un-escaped quotes with an escaped one: `str_replace( array( '\"', '"'), array( '"', '\"'), $str);`

Comment: @WaleedKhan : Thanks for your advice and usually I don't. Though in this case the ONLY character which could mess anything up are double quotes - looked for a quick solution.

Comment: even if you're using deprecated methods such as `mysql_*`, there is still [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) which does that job.

Comment: @nickb, that will fail with this string: `'\\"'`

Comment: @PrinceCherusker a quick fix like this, leads to getting quickly hacked.

Comment: I'd like to point out **a real issue in many StackOverflow questions**. More often than I'd like to I found a question that could've been extremely helpful for me, but all answers were counter-advices due to some unfortunate detail/example explained by the OP. In this case, he wants a Regex solution, and all answers so far are about not applying this to SQL code (might I add SQL isn't even tagged in here). That's not helpful — it's even frustrating for google searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but you're missing two key elements.  The first is that you have to include the quote in the negated character class along with the backslash: `[^"\\]*`.  When that part runs out of things to match, the next character (if there is one) **must** be a quote or a backslash.

If it's a backslash, `\\.` consumes it and the next character, whatever it is.  It might be a quote, a backslash, or anything else; you don't care because you know it's been escaped.  Then you go back to gobbling up non-special characters with `[^"\\]*`.

The other missing element is `\G`.  It anchors the first match to the beginning of the string, just like `\A`.  Each match after that has to start where the previous match ended.  This way, when the final `"` in the regex comes into play, you know that every character before it has been examined, and you are indeed matching an unescaped quote.

```
$str = '"Hello "" """ world!\"';
$str = preg_replace('/\G([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"/', '$1\"', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! :) Honestly I really have to read your description a few more times before I ABSOLUTELY get it - that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you escape your sql:

```
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

or:

```
$str = mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
```

or

```
$str = *_real_escape_string($str);
// * is your db extention
```

Or you can use PDO to parametrize your input.

Comment: Or "best" - placeholders! (But if escaping is required for other reasons, this is *far* better: +1)

Comment: Thanks - though I'm not looking for a solution about escaping strings for SQL (using the mysqli solution btw) but rather for an answer what's wrong about my regex! :)

Comment: @PrinceCherusker, but you shouldn't use regexes because that's always wrong.

Comment: *"I wish to understand what is wrong with the follow regular expression/approach"*. He might have used the SQL merely as a context example. Saying "it's not a good idea" and elaborate on alternarives is like refusing to answer his question IMO.

Comment: @caiosm1005, You can't do it with a regular expression. That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: @TylerCrompton what exactly do you mean can't be done with regex? Escaping quotation marks?

Comment: I mean I guess you *could*, but it's not really a regular language, so it shouldn't be done with regular expressions. But *if* it is still desired despite the nonsemanticness and the abundance of warnings, one could do use `/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"/g`. The non-capturing group part would have to remain the same so that the correct number of backslashes are used; otherwise, the number of backslashes would be reduced by 50%.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I'm not familiar with `(?:)`, but through testing I wasn't able to restore the matched ``\``s preceding `"` through backreferences (e.g.: replacing value `$1"` in PHP). Wouldn't `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*"` fit better?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22296/discussion-between-tyler-crompton-and-caiosm1005)